# SQL count number of users every 7 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and I need to find `count` of users every 7 days. I have a table with users for every single day starting from April 2015 up until now:

```
...
2015-05-16 00:00
2015-05-16 00:00
2015-05-17 00:00
2015-05-17 00:00
2015-05-17 00:00
2015-05-17 00:00
2015-05-17 00:00
2015-05-18 00:00
2015-05-18 00:00
...
```

and I need to count the number of users every 7 days (weekly) so I have data weekly.

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), Activity_Date FROM TABLE_NAME
```

I need output like this:

```
TotalUsers   week1  week2 week3 ..........and so on
  82              80     14    16
```

I am using DB Visualizer to query Oracle database.

Comment: What's wrong with this? Remember to replace `TABLE_NAME` with the name of the table you want the information to come out of.

Comment: more description neede..like 7 days past from today,or the week... share your table design it will help people to answer accurately

Comment: I've just edited my post.

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on the error message from the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try following,

```
Select 
  sum(Week1) + sum(Week2) + sum(Week3) + sum(Week4) + sum(Week5) as Total,
  sum(Week1) as Week1,
  sum(Week2) as Week2,
  sum(Week3) as Week3,
  sum(Week4) as Week4,
  sum(Week5) as Week5
From (
  select 
    case when week = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Week1,
    case when week = 2 then 1 else 0 end as Week2,
    case when week = 3 then 1 else 0 end as Week3,
    case when week = 4 then 1 else 0 end as Week4,
    case when week = 5 then 1 else 0 end as Week5
  from 
  (
      Select
        CEILING(datepart(dd,visitdate)/7+1) week,
        user_id
      from visitor
  )T
)D
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27f65/12)

You need to add month & year in the result as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), Activity_Date FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Activity_Date > '2015-06-31';
```

That would get the amount of users for the last 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define your weeks? Here's an approach for SQL Server that starts each seven-day block relative to the start of April. The expressions will vary according to your specific needs:

```
select
    dateadd(
        dd,
        datediff(dd, cast('20150401' as date), Activity_Date) / 7 * 7,
        cast('20150401' as date)
    ) as WeekStart,
    count(*)
from T
group by datediff(dd, cast('20150401' as date), Activity_Date) / 7
```

Oracle:

```
select
    trunc(Activity_date, 'DAY') as WeekStart,
    count(*)
from T
group by trunc(Activity_date, 'DAY') /* D and DAY are the same thing */
```

Comment: I tried it but it throws an error  **Error Code: 904, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": incorrect identifier**

Comment: You're using Oracle which is why I mentioned SQL Server specifically. You can probably try `trunc(Activity_date, 'D')` instead.

Comment: Thanks, however I need the count of users for that particular week, not count of all users from the start in this week. Just for that week.

Comment: Every week in a range that I have the table for. I have data starting from May up until today so I need to count the users for every week (7 days) in this range.

Comment: I'm wondering if you actually tried the query above. Since I answered you've changed your question to request a pivoted single row. Unless I got the wrong argument ('D') this should break out into week by week totals.

Answer (score 0):

This is my test table:

```
user_id  act_date
1   01/04/2015
2   01/04/2015
3   04/04/2015
4   05/04/2015
..
```

This is my query:

```
select week_offset, count(*) nb from (
select trunc((act_date-to_date('01042015','DDMMYYYY'))/7) as week_offset from test_date)
group by week_offset
order by 1
```

and this is the output:

```
week_offset  nb
0   6
1   3
4   5
5   7
6   3
7   1
18  1
```

Week offset is the number of the week from 01/04/2015, and we can show the first day of the week.
See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64264/1) for live testing.